# Mixing lists in python

Tags: python, list

```
from itertools import product

x_coord = ['a','b','c','d','e']
y_coord = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

board = []
index = 0

for item in itertools.product(x_coord, y_coord): 

    board += item

    for elements in board:

        board[index] = board[index] + board[index +1]
        board.remove(board[index +1])
        index += 1


print board
```

---

Hello. Let me explain what I want to do with that:

I have two lists(`x_coord` and `y_coord`) and I want to mix them like that:

```
board = ['a1', 'a2', ..., 'e1', 'e2', ...]
```

But I get the `IndexError: list index out of range` error instead of that.

How should I proceed?

OBS.:If there's any type of error in my english, please tell me. I'm learning english as well as code.

Comment: What is your expected output of `board` supposed to be?  `product()` is returning a tuple of the two items in the lists you are iterating.  So `[x + y for x, y in product(x_coord, y_coord)]` will be that list you put in your example

Comment: Ops, sorry about that. I would have put board instead of coord in my example of what I wanted:

board  = ['a1', 'a2', ..., 'e1', 'e2', ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like that,

```
>>> x_coord = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> y_coord = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> [item + item2 for item2 in y_coord for item in x_coord]
['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3', 'a4', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4', 'e4', 'a5', 'b5', 'c5', 'd5', 'e5']
```

Sorted results:

```
 >>> sorted([item + item2 for item2 in y_coord for item in x_coord])
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5']
```

Comment: Nice, but maybe switch the order so it corresponds to OP's output: `[item + item2 for item in x_coord for item2 in y_coord]`

Comment: A little addition would be to use `str` on both lists. This should cover the event wherein the numerical list contains integers and not strings. Not necessary, but a little nice-to-have. Still, +1.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan Already, all items are string.  I think not necessary thanks for advice.

Comment: Thank you. I don't even need to sort, because in the end, ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'...] is even better than what I asked.

Comment: @AdemÖztaş Do you know how could I do something like that:

board = [ [a1, b1, c1, ...], [a2, b2,...], ...]]

Answer (score 0):

```
t = [a + b for a,b in itertools.product(x_coord,y_coord)]
print t % prints what you want
```

Normally `itertools.product(x_coord,y_coord)` will print the following:
[('a', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('a', '3'), ('a', '4'), ('a', '5'), ('b', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('b', '3'), ('b', '4'), ('b', '5'), ('c', '1'), ('c', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('c', '4'), ('c', '5'), ('d', '1'), ('d', '2'), ('d', '3'), ('d', '4'), ('d', '5'), ('e', '1'), ('e', '2'), ('e', '3'), ('e', '4'), ('e', '5')]

As you can see it's already in order because `itertools.product` will multiply `a` by each index in `y_coord` before moving `x_coord` to `b`, etc. etc.

By using `list comprehension` we can combine the two indices using `a+b` for each pair in the output, resulting in this:
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5']

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: I think running it would be easier than me explaining it, but sure, I'll update for an explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
combined = map(lambda x: ''.join(x), product(x_coord, y_coord))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
coord = map(lambda x,y: x+y, x_coord, y_coord)   
print(coord)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x_coord = ['a','b','c','d','e']
y_coord = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
a=[]
for i in range(len(x_coord)):
    for j in range(len(y_coord)):
        a.append(x_coord[i].join(" "+ y_coord[j]))
b=[]
for item in a:
    b.append(item.replace(" ",""))
print b
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to the code you've written.